# memory exhausted uploading an image for greater than 1mb

Tags: php, image, memory, upload

When I try to upload an image above 1 MB, I get an error telling me that my allocated memory has been exhausted, failure etc etc with following script -->

The error which occurs is mentioning line 91 as the culprit

" imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);"

when I try to comment out this line, I don't get an error but just a 'null' stored instead of an upload

--> my server has a 64m limit right now -->

this code is testable at http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com , by uploading an image -- any help appreciated!

```
    function uploadImage($fileName, $maxSize, $maxW, $fullPath, $relPath, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB, $maxH = null){
        $folder = $relPath;
        $maxlimit = $maxSize;
        $allowed_ext = "jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp";
        $match = "";
        $filesize = $_FILES[$fileName]['size'];
        if($filesize > 0){  
            $filename = strtolower($_FILES[$fileName]['name']);
            $filename = preg_replace('/\s/', '_', $filename);
            if($filesize < 1){ 
                $errorList[] = "File size is empty.";
            }
            if($filesize > $maxlimit){ 
                $errorList[] = "File size is too big.";
            }
            if(count($errorList)<1){
                $file_ext = preg_split("/\./",$filename);
                $allowed_ext = preg_split("/\,/",$allowed_ext);
                foreach($allowed_ext as $ext){
                    if($ext==end($file_ext)){
                        $match = "1"; // File is allowed
                        $NUM = time();
                        $front_name = substr($file_ext[0], 0, 15);
                        $newfilename = $front_name."_".$NUM.".".end($file_ext);
                        $filetype = end($file_ext);
                        $save = $folder.$newfilename;
                        if(!file_exists($save)){
                            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                            if($maxH == null){
                                if($width_orig < $maxW){
                                    $fwidth = $width_orig;
                                }else{
                                    $fwidth = $maxW;
                                }
                                $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
                                $fheight = $fwidth/$ratio_orig;

                                $blank_height = $fheight;
                                $top_offset = 0;

                            }else{
                                if($width_orig <= $maxW && $height_orig <= $maxH){
                                    $fheight = $height_orig;
                                    $fwidth = $width_orig;
                                }else{
                                    if($width_orig > $maxW){
                                        $ratio = ($width_orig / $maxW);
                                        $fwidth = $maxW;
                                        $fheight = ($height_orig / $ratio);
                                        if($fheight > $maxH){
                                            $ratio = ($fheight / $maxH);
                                            $fheight = $maxH;
                                            $fwidth = ($fwidth / $ratio);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if($height_orig > $maxH){
                                        $ratio = ($height_orig / $maxH);
                                        $fheight = $maxH;
                                        $fwidth = ($width_orig / $ratio);
                                        if($fwidth > $maxW){
                                            $ratio = ($fwidth / $maxW);
                                            $fwidth = $maxW;
                                            $fheight = ($fheight / $ratio);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if($fheight == 0 || $fwidth == 0 || $height_orig == 0 || $width_orig == 0){
                                    die("FATAL ERROR REPORT ERROR CODE [add-pic-line-67-orig] to <a href='http://www.atwebresults.com'>AT WEB RESULTS</a>");
                                }
                                if($fheight < 45){
                                    $blank_height = 45;
                                    $top_offset = round(($blank_height - $fheight)/2);
                                }else{
                                    $blank_height = $fheight;
                                }
                            }

                            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($fwidth, $blank_height);
                            $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB);

                            imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);
                            switch($filetype){
                                case "gif":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromgif($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "jpg":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "jpeg":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                                case "png":
                                    $image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name']);
                                break;
                            }
                            @imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, $top_offset, 0, 0, $fwidth, $fheight, $width_orig, $height_orig);
                            switch($filetype){
                                case "gif":
                                    if(!@imagegif($image_p, $save)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [GIF]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "jpg":
                                    if(!@imagejpeg($image_p, $save, 100)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [JPG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "jpeg":
                                    if(!@imagejpeg($image_p, $save, 100)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [JPEG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                                case "png":
                                    if(!@imagepng($image_p, $save, 0)){
                                        $errorList[]= "PERMISSION DENIED [PNG]";
                                    }
                                break;
                            }
                            @imagedestroy($filename);
                        }else{
                            $errorList[]= "CANNOT MAKE IMAGE IT ALREADY EXISTS";
                        }   
                    }
                }       
            }
        }else{
            $errorList[]= "NO FILE SELECTED";
        }
        if(!$match){
            $errorList[]= "File type isn't allowed: $filename";
        }
        if(sizeof($errorList) == 0){
            return $fullPath.$newfilename;
        }else{
            $eMessage = array();
            for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($errorList); $x++){
                $eMessage[] = $errorList[$x];
            }
            return $eMessage;
        }
    }

    $filename = strip_tags($_REQUEST['filename']);
    $maxSize = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxSize']);
    $maxW = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxW']);
    $fullPath = strip_tags($_REQUEST['fullPath']);
    $relPath = strip_tags($_REQUEST['relPath']);
    $colorR = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorR']);
    $colorG = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorG']);
    $colorB = strip_tags($_REQUEST['colorB']);
    $maxH = strip_tags($_REQUEST['maxH']);
    $filesize_image = $_FILES[$filename]['size'];
    if($filesize_image > 0){
        $upload_image = uploadImage($filename, $maxSize, $maxW, $fullPath, $relPath, $colorR, $colorG, $colorB, $maxH);
        if(is_array($upload_image)){
            foreach($upload_image as $key => $value) {
                if($value == "-ERROR-") {
                    unset($upload_image[$key]);
                }
            }
            $document = array_values($upload_image);
            for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($document); $x++){
                $errorList[] = $document[$x];
            }
            $imgUploaded = false;
        }else{
            $imgUploaded = true;
            $_SESSION['test']= $upload_image;
        }
    }else{
        $imgUploaded = false;
        $errorList[] = "File Size Empty";
    }
?>
```

Comment: When you say your server has a 64mb limit, is this applied via setting "memory_limit = 64M" in your php.ini file?

Comment: http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/phpinfo.php , actually its showing my max file upload size at 8 mb, i'm on a 'godaddy hosting' for the testing site not sure if it allows php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ini_set('memory_limit', '240M'); in the script

Worked for me; fyi I'm on shared hosting.